# How null byte injection works?

Tags: javascript, security, inject

How does null byte injection work in js? I saw in a write up the following usage in AngularJS: {{7 * 7}} does not work but if you do {{7 * 7}\u0000} it will work. Could someone explain to me exactly how it works?

Comment: http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection

Comment: please add a bit more context.